Django prefetch_related filtered by an attribute of the outer query
I am working on a simple Django application that stores and shows programmes for events:

There is a table of Participants, which are also used in Django's auth system.
Each Participant can have multiple Affiliations with a number of Institutes.
Each Affiliation has a (nullable) start and end timestamp.
Each Slot represents a single activity (talk, meal, workshop) and has a start timestamp. Multiple people can be assigned to each slot.

class Participant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    institutes = models.ManyToManyField('Institute', through='Affiliation', related_name='people')
    
class Institute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    
class Affiliation(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Participant', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='affiliation')
    institute = models.ForeignKey('Institute', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='affiliation')
    start = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class Slot(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=256)
    abstract = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=4096)
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    person = models.ManyToManyField('Participant', related_name='slots', blank=True)

I would like to show a single Slot and the people responsible, along with their Affiliations, but only those that are valid at the beginning of that event (where start is null or earlier than Slot.start, and end is null or later than Slot.start).
I have written a QuerySet method for that, and by itself it is working correctly, as I could verify with manage.py shell:
class ParticipantQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def with_current_affiliations(self, date: datetime.date = None):
        date = date or datetime.date.today()
        return self.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'affiliation',
                queryset=Affiliation.objects.with_institute().filter(
                    Q(start__lte=date) | Q(start__isnull=True),
                    Q(end__gte=date) | Q(end__isnull=True)
                ),
                to_attr='current_affiliations',
            ),
        )

Calling it from where I actually need it (DetailView of Slot) does not do what I would like it to do. I am missing a way of referring to the start attribute of Slot.
class SlotQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def with_people(self):
        Participant = apps.get_model('core', 'Participant')

        return self.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'person',
                queryset=Participant.objects.with_current_affiliations(???)),
                to_attr='people',
            )
        )      

class SlotView(DetailView):
    model = Slot

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.with_people()          

My question is: What to put instead of ??? here, so that it refers to the original Slot's start and so that only Affiliations that are valid at that time are returned?

F('start') refers to start of the Affiliation (which is then compared  __gte with itself, so it returns all Affiliations).
F('person__slots__start') returns a list of valid affiliations for all Slots of that Participant, even if they are not related to the Slot in question.
OuterRef('start') obviously cannot be used directly, as Prefetch is not a subquery.
Subquery(Slot.objects.filter(person__id=OuterRef('id')).values('start')) does not solve the problem: I still cannot refer to the outer query's start, only fetch all Slots' starts, so only the Affiliations valid at the time of the oldest Slot are returned.

